# PhpStorm 9 multiple console

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I've just installed PhpStorm 9 and read the [What's new in PHPStorm 9](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/)
I met some new usefull tool as:

> Multiple Consoles per data source, now with a schema switcher, local history, and easier access

But I can't find where I can create one more database console per one data source.

**UPD**
I found one more option to open new console: Right click on `dataSource name in Database Navigator panel` and choose `New -> Console`. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [IntelliJ Web Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-database-consoles.html):

To manage your database consoles, use the Scratches view of the Project tool window.

[image]

[image]

To create new consoles, select the target data source or a node within it, and do one of the following:

- Select `File | New | Console` from the main menu.
- Select `New | Console` from the context menu
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> and select `Console`.